# Ionic + Angular Charts: Uncaught Error: Chart.js library needs to included

Tags: angularjs, charts, ionic-framework, chart.js

I am trying to include charts into my Ionic application, but I get error.
I have download the angular.js folder and chart.js folder into my lib folder and added the following lines to index.html:

```
<script src="lib/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js"></script>
<script src="lib/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

I also added chart.js to my module: angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'chart.js']) but I still get the error: Uncaught Error: Chart.js library needs to included

What am I doing wrong, how can I use chart.js in my app?

Comment: have you tried putting `<script src="lib/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>` before `angular-chart.js`?

Comment: Please try importing Chart.js or Chart.min.js. You shouldn't import both, as they are exactly the same. The .min stands for minified, which means it just as all unnessesary characters (spaces, breaklines etc) removed to make the file size smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix was to put  before angular-chart.js as Jossef Harush implied as a comment in my post. 
Also it is redundant to import both ”min” and normal js files

Comment: I ran into the same issue. I kept thinking, ok, I have the scripts included in the html and module referenced in the angular controller, why is this a problem? I needed to think way back to the basics, that a dependent script should be loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

include js in this order

```
<script src="lib/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>

<script src="lib/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
```