# angular.module('myapp',['chart.js']) Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, charts

I am new at Working with Angular.JS. Want to make chart using chart.js

I've installed chart.js with

npm install angular-chart.js --save

```
.state('index.dashboard', {
            url: "/dashboard",
            templateUrl: "modules/dashboard/dashboard.html",
            controller: 'dashboardController',
            data: { pageTitle: 'Dashboard' },
            resolve: {
                loadPlugin: function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                            serie: true,
                            files: ['css/plugins/c3/c3.min.css', 'js/plugins/chartJs/Chart.min.js', 'js/plugins/d3/d3.min.js', 'js/plugins/c3/c3.min.js']
                        }, {
                            serie: true,
                            name: 'gridshore.c3js.chart',
                            files: ['js/plugins/c3/c3-angular.min.js']
                        }, {
                            serie: true,
                            name: 'angular-dygraphs',
                            files: ['bower_components/angular-dygraphs/src/angular-dygraphs.js']
                        }, {
                            serie: true,
                            files: ['css/style_2.css', 'js/plugins/highcharts/highstock.src.js']
                        }, {
                            serie: true,
                            name: 'highcharts-ng',
                            files: ['js/plugins/highcharts/highcharts-ng.js']
                        },{
                            serie: true,
                            name:"chart.js",
                            files:['js/plugins/chartJs/angular-chart.js']
                        },
                        //               {
                        // name: 'chart.js',
                        //                   files: ['bower_components/Chart.Zoom.js/src/chart.zoom.js']
                        // //               },
                        //               {
                        //                   name: 'angles',
                        //                   files: ['js/plugins/chartJs/angles.js']
                        //               },
                        {
                            files: ['css/plugins/jsTree/style.min.css', 'js/plugins/jsTree/jstree.min.js', 'css/plugins/iCheck/custom.css', 'js/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js']
                        }, {
                            name: 'ngJsTree',
                            files: ['js/plugins/jsTree/ngJsTree.min.js']
                        }, {
                            name: 'cgNotify',
                            files: ['css/plugins/angular-notify/angular-notify.min.css', 'js/plugins/angular-notify/angular-notify.min.js']
                        }
                    ]);
                },
                authenticated: authenticated
            }
        })
```

and now i am adding that to my controller

```
angular.module('inspinia',['chart.js'])
.controller('dashboardController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http',  function($rootScope, $scope, $http) {
var a = 0;
}]);
```

I've tried with

```
angular.module('inspinia')
.controller('dashboardController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http','chart.js',  function($rootScope, $scope, $http) {
var a = 0;
}]);
```

but getting same error of

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Please help me with correct way
Thanks in advcance

Comment: Have you included the JS file using `<script>` in the HTML. And after angularjs.

Comment: Probably missing some script, have you seen https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/ the first lines sugest including `Chart.min.js` and `angular-chart.min.js` in order to use the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to inject chart.js to the controller,

change it as,

```
angular.module('inspinia')
.controller('dashboardController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http',  function($rootScope, $scope, $http) {
var a = 0;
}]);
```

**[DEMO](http://embed.plnkr.co/eExHFQ4TzDxPTaAyq1Vl/)**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41380667/angular-modulemyapp-chart-js-uncaught-error-injectormodulerr/41380684#41380684

Comment: That's new. Why don't you have to inject the chart.js module? It's being used with angularjs there is a module witha provider with that

Comment: chart.js is a module and it is already injected to the module, so not necessary to inject again

Comment: I don't get it, of course you have to inject the module on your module declaration https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/ am I mistaken? Inject the `chart.js` in the module declaration and use the `ChartJsProvider` on your components, right?

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro yes thats the same thing i have explained

Answer (score 1):

1. Include the `angular-chart.js` script tag in your `index.html`, after `angular.js`, as suggested by Tushar.
2. Add `chart.js` as a module dependency when initializing your `inspinia` module, just as you did in your first code snippet.
3. Use the directives provided by the module, there's no need to inject anything in your controllers.

Answer (score 1):

be sure to import it in app.js like:

```
"use strict";

angular.module("yourmodulename",
[
    "ui.router",
     "chart.js" //<-- import it
]);
```

And the use it in your controller ...
Or if you use OcLazy (for lazy loading ) something like:

```
.state("profile.index", {
                url: "/profile",
                templateUrl: "/app/view/template/profilo/profile.html",
                controller: "ProfileController",
                controllerAs: "profileCtrl",
                resolve: {
                    loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load([

                            {
                                name: "chart.js",
                                serie: true,
                                files: ["/app/view/assets/lib/bower/Chart.js/Chart.min.js", "/app/view/assets/lib/bower/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js", "/app/view/assets/lib/bower/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.css"]
                            }
                        ]);
                    }

                }
            })
```

Comment: check how i import it in te second way (oclazy) ..i think you've missed other files:  "/app/view/assets/lib/bower/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js", "/app/view/assets/lib/bower/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.css" specially the js ..cause it give you the angular module

Comment: I've included but without css and now it is giving me Uncaught Error: Chart.js library needs to be included..

Comment: Do I need to include CSS?

Comment: try to do exactly as i wrote:   name: "chart.js",
                                serie: true,
                                files: ["/app/view/assets/lib/bower/Chart.js/Chart.min.js", "/app/view/assets/lib/bower/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js", "/app/view/assets/lib/bower/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.css"]

Comment: there is no angular-ch‌​art.css file I have

Comment: But I've included the Chart.min.js in the same but error is still there

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem but different pages, so i needed to add **EVERY SIGLE PAGE** code snippet and error is gone. However, I didn't understand the reason whey i needed to add.

```
<script src="node_modules/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perhaps this should be a new question if it's slightly different?

Answer (score -1):

Putting

```
<script src="lib/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

before

```
<script src="lib/chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js"></script>
```

solved my problem

And I've removed

> ('myapp',['chart.js'])

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182840/ionic-angular-charts-uncaught-error-chart-js-library-needs-to-included